# How to handle excluded values in a summation or product in Mathematica

Tags: symbolic, summation, conditional, products

I want help to writ that on Wolfram Mathematica  :

[image: summation with excluded value]

[image: product with excluded value]

How can I handle the $i \ne j$ part?

Comment: Did you try `Product[Piecewise[{{(a - a[i])/(a[i] - a[j]), i != j}, {1, True}}], {i,
   1, n}]`? Similar questions were asked and answered a lot.

Comment: Make use of Google translator, this is useful.

Comment: @user64494. Yes I try:  `Product[Piecewise[{{(a - a[i])/(a[i] - a[j]), i != j}, 1, True}}], {i,    1, n}]` give me syntax error ?

Comment: @MariuszIwanyuk: Try `Product[Piecewise[{{(a - a[i])/(a[i] - a[j]), i != j}, {1, True}}], {i,    1, n}]`.

Comment: I amended your question, as I thought it wasn't quite clear. If this is not what you meant, let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are asking how to exclude a single value from summation, i.e. the $i \ne j$ part in your $\sum_{i=0, i\ne j}^n$ example.

You can simply use a conditional, such as [`If`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/If.html) or [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html), to replace the summand with zero for a specific value of $i$.

#### Example

This does not work because it includes $1/0$:

```
In[7]:= Sum[1/k^2, {k, -3, Infinity}]

During evaluation of In[7]:= Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.

Out[7]= ComplexInfinity
```

This works:

```
In[8]:= Sum[If[k == 0, 0, 1/k^2], {k, -3, Infinity}]

Out[8]= 1/36 (49 + 6 π^2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your finite sum exists using a conditional (`If`):

```
Simplify[Sum[If[i === j, 0, (a - Subscript[a, i])/(Subscript[a, i] - Subscript[a, j])], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, n}]]
(*-(1/2) (1 + n)^2*)
```